# LNK1104 cannot open file '...lib.obj'

Tags: c++, compiler-errors, linker-errors

I'm trying to update Visual Studio 2012 C++ projects so that I can compile them in Visual Studio 2015 (Update 3). I've gotten it narrowed down to just one error in one project that I'm completely stumped on:

LNK1104 cannot open file 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\lib.obj'

I've installed all the C++ language options (they don't get installed by default) and even uninstalled and reinstalled Visual Studio.

That file doesn't exist in that directory, and it also doesn't exist in the Visual Studio 2012 directory either.

Anyone have any ideas on how to solve this?

Comment: Can you post the linker command that _VStudio_ generates? That can be found by going to your project options -> _Linker_ -> _Command Line_.

Comment: Turn on VERBOSE mode for the linker to learn more about lib.obj

Comment: Open the property pages and go to C/C++ | Output Files | Object File Name. Any unusual values?

Comment: In the Command Line, I see that the following was added, that is not in the VS 2012 version:

"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\lib" "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\atlmfc\lib" "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.1A\lib"

What would cause those to be added, and do I need them? Obviously the VC\lib one is causing the issues, but why were they added to begin with?

Answer (score 2):

The problem might be that you added something like "$(VC_LibraryPath_x86)xxxx.lib" to the Linker input additional dependencies. This goes wrong, resulting in the error. It should just be "xxxx.lib".

Answer (score 1):

Check your path. If that's correct then make sure you've written xxx.lib rather than xxx