# Error linking to x86.obj

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2015, compiler-errors

Using Visual Studio 2017 RC, I get this compile error:

**LINK : fatal error LNK1181: cannot open input file 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.10.24728\lib\x86.obj'**

x86.obj does not exist on my system. Yet, the compiler wants to link to it, although I have not instructed so in the project properties. Does it misinterpret a folder name ($(VC_LibraryPath_x86)) as an object to which it has to link? Could it be a bug?

On the other hand, I found out that a similar problem also occurs in Visual Studio 2015, there is even an (unanswered) question on it: [LNK1104 cannot open file '...lib.obj'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38752320/lnk1104-cannot-open-file-lib-obj?newreg=915c6093f3684d6c8a8fa303290a2807)

Does anyone have an idea what is going wrong here? Thanks.

--
Diagnostic build output:

LINK : fatal error LNK1104: cannot open file 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.10.24728\lib\x86.obj'
The command exited with code 1104.
Output Property: LinkSkippedExecution=False
Done executing task "Link" -- FAILED.

Comment: What are you trying to build? What platform are you targeting?

Comment: Windows10 x86. I am trying to build a DLL from rather old code. It compiled well in VS2008. (It does not give other compile errors than the one mentioned.)

Comment: Everything, up to and including x86, is the name of a directory.  In other words, the linker was told to link a file named ".obj".  No filename, like "foo.obj".  Pretty hard to guess how that happened when you don't show a build trace.

Comment: I added the diagnostic build output. Not sure what you mean with a "build trace".

Comment: As with the unanswered questions, make the linker options VERBOSE and paste the whole linker command here

Comment: I just found out what the problem is. I added "$(VC_LibraryPath_x86)msvcrt.lib" to the Linker input additional dependencies. This goes wrong, resulting in the error. It should just be "msvcrt.lib".